# How to use separators in pathlib to acces another file/folder

Tags: python, ctypes, pathlib

I have a script that changes the Windows background image considering the current time of the day (day or night). I wanted to make this script scalable in order to be used on another computer without any change in the code.

```
from datetime import datetime, time
import pandas
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path

file_path = "myfile.xlsx" #sunrise/sunset file path
print(file_path)
data = pandas.read_excel(file_path, header=0) #Header on line 0

#Today as day number in reference to 1st of Jan
day = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday

#Today's parameters
#sr and ss are column names in the Excel spreadsheet for sunrise and sunset respectively
#Minus 1 to account for 0 based indexing
sunrise = data["sr"][day - 1]
sunset = data["ss"][day - 1] 

#Function to convert time objects into integers
def seconds_in_time(time_value: time):
    return (time_value.hour * 60 + time_value.minute) * 60 + time_value.second

notification_minutes = 5
notification_seconds = notification_minutes * 60
#Variable for a moment in time 5 minutes before the sunset
sunset_minus_five = seconds_in_time(sunset) - notification_seconds

#Setting up the day_night variable depending on the now variable
#delta calculates the difference in seconds between now and sunset -during night- and sunrise -during day-
#A negative value for delta means that now variable is equal to any moment between midnight and the sunrise  
if now > sunrise and now < sunset:
    day_night = 'day'
    delta = (seconds_in_time(now) - seconds_in_time(sunrise))
else:
    day_night = 'night'
    delta = (seconds_in_time(now) - seconds_in_time(sunset))
    
#delta_notification calculates the difference in seconds between now and sunset_minus_five
delta_notification = seconds_in_time(now) - sunset_minus_five

abs_path = Path().resolve()
print(abs_path)
sep = '\\'
target_path = abs_path + sep + day_night + '.jpg'
print(target_path)

#Function to change the wallpaper
def changeBG(target_path):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 3) #SystemParametersInfoW for x64 architecture

#Wallpaper when code is ran user log on
#changeBG(target_path)
```

This code returns me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ca377c654d5c> in <module>
     42 print(abs_path)
     43 sep = '\\'
---> 44 target_path = abs_path + sep + day_night + '.jpg'
     45 print(target_path)
     46 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
```

Before coming to this `pathlib` approach I have tried a *static* approach with:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Sunset\\wallpapers_desktop_only\\'+ day_night +'\\'+ vmc_imc_day_night() +'.jpg'

#Function to change the wallpaper
def changeBG(path):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 3) #SystemParametersInfoW for x64 architecture
```

This has worked without any problems since the separator that `ctypes` is expecting is `\\`, but `pathlib` returns me `\` which cannot be used as a string.

How can I use `pathlib` in order to use any files/directories that are inside my working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathlib` doesn't work the way you are using it.
When using pathlib is saves you from adding the separators yourself, and you can concatenate paths by using the `/` operator (which is overridden in the package)

You should try:

```py
target_path = abs_path / f'{day_night}.jpg'
```

Comment: I have tried this and now I'm getting `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` .

Comment: What version of python are you using? f-strings are supported on python3.6 and up. and are you sure you use `/` and not `\\`?

Comment: Python 3.8.5. However, I have tried `target_path = abs_path / '{}.jpg'.format(day_night)` as one person suggested in this thread and this solution seems to be working.

Comment: That's weird, can you comment the code you used and more details? you should use `f-strings` and not `.format` in new versions of python

Comment: This is exactly the code I used: `#The path the folder
abs_path = Path().resolve()
#The path to the wallpapers being used
path = abs_path / day_night / '{}.jpg'.format(vmc_imc_day_night())` and seems to be working. However! I now have problems in translating this path to the ctypes function which should be changing my background image since it is expecting another type of path that uses // as a separator. I might be making another thread for this issue.

Comment: just create the path using pathlib, and when sending it as a parameter to the ctypes function use `str(target_path)`.

Comment: and `path = abs_path / day_night / f'{vmc_imc_day_night()}.jpg'` should work

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you cannot concatenate str and WindowsPath,
try to use:

```
target_path = abs_path / '{}.jpg'.format(day_night)
```